# Format a negative timedelta as string with sign and hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: python, timedelta

Positive and negative timedeltas are formatted differently when casting them to string in Python:

```
import datetime

str(datetime.timedelta(hours=2))    
--> '2:00:00'

str(datetime.timedelta(hours=-2))    
--> '-1 day, 22:00:00'
```

I would rather like to have my negative timedeltas formatted like the positive ones but with a negativity indicator, as in `-2:00:00`.

Can this be achieved somehow?

**edit:**

After looking through the linked answer, I came up with this:

```
def timedelta_to_string(timedelta):
    total_seconds = timedelta.total_seconds()
    if total_seconds < 0:
        timedelta_str = '-' + str(datetime.timedelta() - timedelta)
    else:
        timedelta_str = str(timedelta)
    return timedelta_str
```

This gives:

```
timedelta_to_string(datetime.timedelta(hours=2))
>>> '2:00:00'

timedelta_to_string(datetime.timedelta(hours=-2))
>>> '-2:00:00'

timedelta_to_string(datetime.timedelta(hours=30))
>>>'1 day, 6:00:00'

timedelta_to_string(datetime.timedelta(hours=-30))
>>> '-1 day, 6:00:00'
```

Having days being shown for timedeltas > 24 hours is fine with me.
Is there any edge case that I am missing that would not work with this approach?

Comment: `str(datetime.timedelta() - timedelta)` can be written a bit more concisely as `str(-1 * timedelta)`