# Subtract time only from two datetime columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I am looking to do something like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54166156/adding-subtracting-datetime-time-columns-pandas). However, I only want to subtract the `time` component of the two `datetime` columns.

For eg., given this dataframe:

```
                  ts1        ts2
0 2018-07-25 11:14:00        2018-07-27 12:14:00
1 2018-08-26 11:15:00        2018-09-24 10:15:00
2 2018-07-29 11:17:00        2018-07-22 11:00:00
```

The expected output for `ts2 -ts1` time component only should give:

```
                  ts1                        ts2                ts_delta
0 2018-07-25 11:14:00        2018-07-27 12:14:00                1:00:00
1 2018-08-26 11:15:00        2018-09-24 10:15:00               -1:00:00
2 2018-07-29 11:17:00        2018-07-22 11:00:00               -0:17:00
```

So, for row `0`: the time for `ts2` is `12:14:00`, the time for `ts1` is `11:14:00`. The expected output is just these two times subtracting (don't care about the `days`). In this case:

`12:14:00` - `11:14:00` = `1:00:00`.

How would I do this in one single line?

Comment: can you further specify what the conditions are for your desired output? Because you state it should be ts2 - ts1, but that is not what you show.

Comment: All the answers have timedelta formatting different from what the OP asked for. How to format them with negative hours, is explained in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797511/format-a-negative-timedelta-as-string-with-sign-and-hours-minutes-seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set both datetimes to a common date first.

One way is to use [`pandas.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

```
o = pd.DateOffset(day=1, month=1, year=2022) # the exact numbers don't matter
# reset dates
ts1 = df['ts1'].add(o)
ts2 = df['ts2'].add(o)
# subtract
df['ts_delta'] = ts2.sub(ts1)
```

As one-liner:

```
df['ts_delta'] = df['ts2'].add((o:=pd.DateOffset(day=1, month=1, year=2022))).sub(df['ts1'].add(o))
```

Other way using a difference between ts2-ts1 (with dates) and ts2-ts1 (dates only):

```
df['ts_delta'] = (df['ts2'].sub(df['ts1'])
                 -df['ts2'].dt.normalize().sub(df['ts1'].dt.normalize())
                 )
```

output:

```
                  ts1                 ts2          ts_delta
0 2018-07-25 11:14:00 2018-07-27 12:14:00   0 days 01:00:00
1 2018-08-26 11:15:00 2018-09-24 10:15:00 -1 days +23:00:00
2 2018-07-29 11:17:00 2018-07-22 11:00:00 -1 days +23:43:00
```

*NB. don't get confused by the `-1 days +23:00:00`, this is actually the ways to represent `-1hour`*

Comment: While this does not format the outcome in negative time, I can combine this solution with @Joooeey comment for my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want the *time difference* and you're not working with timezone-aware datetime, the date does not matter. Therefore you don't have to change any dates or set some arbitrary reference date. Just work with what you have.

Subtract ts1's time component from ts2 as a timedelta, then convert the resulting datetime to a timedelta by subtracting ts2' date:

```py
df["delta_time"] = (df["ts2"] - pd.to_timedelta(df["ts1"].dt.time.astype(str))) - df["ts2"].dt.floor("d")

df
                  ts1                 ts2        delta_time
0 2018-07-25 11:14:00 2018-07-27 12:14:00   0 days 01:00:00
1 2018-08-26 11:15:00 2018-09-24 10:15:00 -1 days +23:00:00
2 2018-07-29 11:17:00 2018-07-22 11:00:00 -1 days +23:43:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to simulate your problem in my local environment. Apparently `pandas.datetime64' types supporting add/subtract operations. You don't actually need to access` datetime` object to execute these operations.

I did my experiments as below;

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['2018-07-25 11:14:00', '2018-08-26 11:15:00', '2018-07-29 11:17:00'],
                   'b' : ['2018-07-27 12:14:00', '2018-09-24 10:15:00', '2018-07-22 11:00:00'] })

df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a'])
df['b'] = pd.to_datetime(df['b'])

df['d'] = df['b'] - df['a']
```

and df is like;

```
    a                   b                   d
0   2018-07-25 11:14:00 2018-07-27 12:14:00 2 days 01:00:00
1   2018-08-26 11:15:00 2018-09-24 10:15:00 28 days 23:00:00
2   2018-07-29 11:17:00 2018-07-22 11:00:00 -8 days +23:43:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first strip time, then put time on same day, subtract, and take absolute value.

```
l = lambda x: pd.to_datetime("01-01-1900 " + x)

df["ts_delta"] = (
    df["ts2"].dt.time.astype(str).apply(l) - df["ts1"].dt.time.astype(str).apply(l)
).abs()
df
```

Output:

```
                  ts1                 ts2        ts_delta
0 2018-07-25 11:14:00 2018-07-27 12:14:00 0 days 01:00:00
1 2018-08-26 11:15:00 2018-09-24 10:15:00 0 days 01:00:00
2 2018-07-29 11:17:00 2018-07-22 11:00:00 0 days 00:17:00
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `df['col_name'].dt.time` to get time from date time column. Let's assume your dataframe name is df. Now, in your case

```
t1 = df['ts1'].dt.time
t2 = df['ts2'].dt.time

df['ts_delta'] = t2 - t1
```

For single line

```
df['ts_delta'] = df['ts2'].dt.time - df['ts1'].dt.time
```

I hope it will resolve your issue. Happy Coding!

Comment: I have already tried that. This is the error message ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'```